# Filter linked list and return new linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

I am trying to filter a linked list. Since I don't want to change the original linked list, I want to create a sub linked list and return it instead.

I am having troubles with this because I only know how to get 1 node from the filtering process, but I don't know how to move around and add nodes from the original linked list to the sub linked list.

I have a struct like this (This represents an entry in a hash table):

```
typedef struct Entry {
   char *word;
   int len;
   struct Entry *next;
} Entry;
```

My filter function will receive the word length and the original linked list as arguments, then find nodes that have the same value of len. Whenever it finds a node that has the same value of len, it adds the node to another linked list. Finally it returns the new linked list.

```
struct Entry* filterLen(int len, struct Entry *en) {
   struct Entry *temp = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));

   while(en->next != NULL) {
      if (en->len == len) {
         // assign values to temp list
         temp->word = en->word;
         temp->len = en->len;
         temp->next = en;
      }

      en = en->next; // move through list
   }

   return temp;
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: You already have the old linked list so presumably you also already have generic code to add entries to a linked list. So, use that code to add the new, cloned entries to a *new* linked list.

Answer (score 2):

```
Entry* filterLen(int len, Entry *en) {
   Entry *result = NULL, **temp = &result;

   while(en != NULL) {
      if (en->len == len) {
     // assign values to temp list
         *temp = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
         (*temp)->word = en->word;
         (*temp)->len = en->len;
         (*temp)->next = NULL;
         temp = &((*temp)->next);
      }

      en = en->next; // move through list
  }

  return result;
}
```

EDIT
Seems to be a competition here, so:

```
Entry* filterLen(int len, Entry *en) {
   Entry *result, **temp = &result;

   for ( ; en; en = en->next) { // Move through list
      if (en->len == len) {        // Then assign values to temp list
         *temp = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
         (*temp)->word = en->word; // WARNING str shared with en list!!!
         (*temp)->len = en->len;
         temp = &((*temp)->next);
      }
   }
   *temp = NULL;
   return result;
}
```

Comment: How is this code able to return more than 1 node in the result? There's no linking of nodes that I can see. Not to mention the memory leaks that occur (due to dangling pointers) if more than one node matches.

Comment: @AlanAu Just forgot one line. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: @MikkelChristiansen fyi, you can toss out the `(*temp)->next = NULL;` within the loop and just do `*temp = NULL;` right before the `return` statement. And you may need to deep copy the `word` member, btw. That isn't exactly clear from the OP's post, however.

Comment: @WhozCraig I know, but this is closer to the original.

Answer (score 2):

```
Entry* filterLen(int len, Entry *en) {
    Entry result = { NULL, 0, NULL };
    Entry *curr  = &result;

    while(en != NULL){
        if(en->len == len){
            Entry *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
            *temp = *en;
            temp->next = NULL;
            curr = curr->next = temp;
        }
        en = en->next;
    }
    return result.next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood in you question, you want to return a linked list of entries with a len field equal to the input parameter. Currently, your code is only storing a single 'temp' and you need to rebuild a new list.

```
struct Entry* filterLen(int len, struct Entry *en) {
  struct Entry *first = NULL;
  struct Entry *last = NULL;
  while(en != NULL) {
    if (en->len == len) {
      if(last){
        last->next = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
        last = last->next;
      } else {
        last = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
        first = last;
      }
      // assign values to temp list
      last->word = en->word;
      last->len = en->len;
      last->next = NULL;
    }
    en = en->next; // move through list
  }
  return first;
```

}

Comment: Your while condition is wrong. It should be while(en != NULL). And what is it you return?

Comment: You're right, I reused part of the original code, and forgot to change the incorrect while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your filtering function is copying the contents of the last node it found (including the `next` pointer) into the `temp` node.  This results in the function returning the last matching node plus whatever comes after it in the list.

What you need to do is create a new node each time you find a matching node and copy the contents to that node.  That includes duplicating the string so you don't have to worry about potentially double-freeing anything.

```
struct Entry* filterLen(int len, struct Entry *en) {
   struct Entry *result = NULL, *temp = NULL;

   while(en != NULL) {
      if (en->len == len) {
         // copy node to end of temp list
         if (temp == NULL) {
             result =  malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
             temp = result;
         } else {
             temp->next =  malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
             temp = temp->next;
         }
         temp->word = strdup(en->word);  // Perform a deep copy
         temp->len = en->len;
         temp->next = NULL;
      }

      en = en->next; // move through list
   }

   return result;
}
```